# Markdown to html automatically on a site

Tags: html, markdown

I know i can convert an MD file to HTML with a bunch of scripts.

I become part of a site which is hosted on github, and it has a `place_holder.md` file. I can view its content if i isit to `place_holder` domain. If i change anything in the md file, and i push it to the repo it get updated immediately. If i visit the `place_holder.html` i can see its content, even that the file is not in the github repo

So my question is:

Does github hoster stuff has an auto md  converter which i cannot see? In this case where can i get something like this?

Do webbrowsers understand markdown by default? Then why dont i see `place_holder.md` in the url?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is quite vague. There are several ways to achieve what you are asking for. It's be easier to find a good solution to your problem if you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37547168/edit) your question and specify your scenario a little more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i visit the place_holder.html i can see its content, even that the file is not in the github repo

Of course you can look at the `place_holder.html` file it is an html file on your computer that your browser can render so you can view it.

> Does github hoster stuff has an auto md converter which i cannot see?

I do not believe github has an *"auto md converter"*.

> In this case where can i get something like this?

You can use [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to convert your plain text and markdown to static html pages which you can host on the web. You also can get text editors to preview your markdown before you convert it into html which can be helpful. Here is one online [text editor.](https://stackedit.io/)

Comment: Thanks, i guess that is the case. I ll look for jekyll.

Comment: Yeah jekyll is really good for starting your own blog page or a website that doesn't need to be changed often. I use jekyll to render my markdown for my blog.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're asking to implement this, but take a look at [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked). It's super easy to use and very flexible.